# How can I submit multiple django forms with one button at once with jquery?

Tags: python, jquery, django

I have a single page application consisting of multiple forms (It's not possible for me to use only one form, as I need to validate ).
At a button press, I need to submit each form, somehow catch the response and only redirect the page if one of those forms is invalid.

In my view, I return `HttpResponse(status=204)` if a single form is valid or `render(request, 'home.html', context)` if a form is invalid.

I tried this, but it's obviously not working. Is there a way to submit multiple forms and do nothing, if a response is 204?

```js
    $('#download-btn').click(function () {

        $("form").each(function () {
            $(this).submit(); // Seems to only submit one form
            // Don't redirect page here, so that all forms get submitted
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment otherwise I would've. But if your forms have html "id"s -- you can "get" the html object by id and validate more easily like this:

let leagueElement = document.getElementById("selectLeague");
let leagueValue = leagueElement.options[leagueElement.selectedIndex].value;

Also instead of it being a submit type -- I've had more luck with Submit buttons like so:

Submit

You can have the "onclick" element be the "form name" and have a global variable that counts how many forms have been "clicked" then check if they are all good to go once the variable shows that all forms are submitted-- a part of your function that you call from each submit "button" can be performed i.e. the "validate forms" and throw error or "validate forms and submit with 204"